# How to convert List(Of String) to Object()?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I know what you're thinking, why do you want to convert in that direction?  Basically, I have to make modern code palatable for a legacy COM+ app.I've seen a lot of conversion ideas going the other direction.

The only thing I've come up with it actually looping through the List(Of String).  Perhaps this is the best/only way.

This works, but seems cludgey.
groupNames is a List(Of String)

```
Dim groups() As Object = New Object() {}

If groupNames IsNot Nothing Then
    groups = New Object(groupNames.Count - 1) {}
    For i = 0 To groupNames.Count - 1
        groups(i) = groupNames(i)
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Not sure this is what you're looking for `groupNames.Cast<Object>().ToArray()`

Comment: Yes it is, and yes I feel dumb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little cleaner if you use the LINQ `Cast` extension method:

```
Dim strings As New List(Of String)({"1", "2"})
Dim objects() As Object = strings.Cast(Of Object).ToArray()
```

Comment: I still have to do a null check on "strings" because it's passed in as a parameter to my method... but this is what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use good old array here. There is no need to lose strong typed behaviour.

Comment: You're talking about covariance I think, that is broken, will fail when try to set a value.

Comment: I am referring to string array.

Comment: but op is asking for object[]

Comment: I do need object[] because the COM component throws a type mismatch when it gets a string[]

Comment: VB6 typing is different than .net.

Comment: I don't have any VB6 IDE nor the patience to deal with that language. But, it does support string arrays.

Comment: VB6 does support string arrays, but if you have an old com component that has a parameter defined as Variant, and that Variant is used in the code as an object array, then you can't pass a string array, you will get a type mismatch.